# Zero set of analytic function of two-variables smooth

Tags: polynomials, power-series, analytic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a real-analytic function of two-variables.  Further suppose that $f(x,y)=0$ has at least one solution for all $x$ in some neighborhood $B_r = (x_0-r,x_0+r)$. Call this largest solution $\gamma(x)$. I believe that $\gamma \colon B_r \to \mathbb R$ defines a curve.

Is $\gamma$ continuous at $x_0$? How about smooth?

Comment: The question isn't exactly the same, but I think that this question can be closed as duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207094/the-hausdorff-dimension-of-the-zero-set-of-a-real-analytic-function), since the accepted answer shows that the answer here is affirmative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Hausdorff dimension of the zero set of a real analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207094/the-hausdorff-dimension-of-the-zero-set-of-a-real-analytic-function)